# How can one float "down" multiple divs?

Tags: html

My current example is (float left, div is filled from left to right):

[image]

Is there any way to change it to this? Sadly, there's no 'float: down'.

[image]

Comment: you need to post some code, otherwise how are we supposed to know what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

With Flexbox is pretty easy:

```css
.container {
  background-color: bisque;
  width:250px;
  height:400px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.element {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: lime;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  margin:10px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
</div>
```